# npm: Как обеспечить видимый результат внесённых изменений при написании css-библиотек и работающих с dom библиотек?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm

Предположим, Вы пишите npm-библиотеку, аналог фреймворка bootstrap, включающий в себя стили и скрипты. Возникает вопрос: а как во время разработки увидеть глазами результат Вашей работы? В вопросе я указал "css и работающих с dom библиотек" потому, что веду разговор о таких библиотеках, которые дают именно видимый в браузере результат, а если мы пишем просто какие-то утилиты, то тут проблема решается написанием юнит-теста.

Подробно объясню, какие проблемы я бы хотел решить.

Конечно, можно настроить gulp-файл, прописать компиляцию css-препроцессоров, сборку скриптов webpack-ом, наблюдение за файлами с автоматический пересборкой и перезагрузкой браузера и так далее. Под каждую группу компонентов, типа кнопок или полей ввода делаем отдельную html-страницу, где и будем во время редактирования стилей и скриптов проверять отображение в браузере. В итоге, библиотека тут же обрастёт файлами, которые пользователям не нужны.

Можно эти не нужные пользователям файлы не коммитить в репозиторий. Но что, если над библиотекой работают несколько человек? Наверное, сделать отдельную ветвь development... Эта ветвь требует больше npm-зависимостей, чем master (gulp, препроцессоры, webpack, перезагрузка браузера и т. д.), а потому при переключении между ветвями предстоит каждый раз переустанавливать npm-зависимости.

Но настоящий ад начнётся, когда библиотека уже будет готова к использованию, при этом, как обычно, в ней **поначалу** будет обнаруживаться куча багов и недоработок. Порочный круг будет состоять из следующих звеньев:

1. Начали использовать библиотеку в проекте - обнаружили баг.
2. Закрыли проект - открыли проект с библиотекой.
3. Исправили код.
4. Если у нас нет средств для просмотра результатов, то проверить, нормально ли мы подправили, например, стили кнопок или полей ввода, можно только в проекте, где библиотека используется.
5. Коммитим патч в удалённый репозиторий библиотеки
6. Обновляем зависимости в проекте, где эта библиотека используется.
7. Смотрим результат

Если окажется, что требуется ещё чуть-чуть подправить, или будет обнаружен новый баг, придётся повторить все выше перечисленные шаги.

Comment: "В итоге, библиотека тут же обрастёт файлами, которые пользователям не нужны." Мне почему-то всегда казалось, что для этих целей придумали `dev-dependencies` и `.npmignore`. Или я что-то в этой жизни не понимаю?

Comment: @Spomni, про `.npmignore` не знал. Попробую.